# How can I delete relationships belonging to a node using Cypher in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have a node, and I want to delete all of the relationships for that node. I've tried to use `MATCH (node) DELETE node;` but I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher prevents accidental deletion of relationships.  You need to use the `DETACH` keyword, which will remove relationships from a node you are deleting. The following should work and delete everything in the database:

```
MATCH (node) DETACH DELETE node;
```